# Eclipse в пункте new есть только project examle other

Tags: java, eclipse

не кидайте тапками я только учусь. При открытии уже существующего проекта в Eclipse в проводнике при выборе new пропали пункты по java остались только project.. examle.. other..
У меня сейчас так
[image: У меня сейчас так]

А вот как было раньше и должно быть
[image: А вот как было раньше и должно быть]

Comment: у еклипса динамическое меню, меняется в зависимости от того, какое окно активно.

Comment: В том то и дело все везде java, да и добавить и class и  package я могу если выбрать other но почему eclipse не определяет что проект java и в меню new не выводит соответствующие пункты

Comment: если это не java проект, то зачем ему меню?

Comment: @RomanC в том то и дело проект java, не знаю как правильно добавлять сюда фото , надеюсь так [Скрин](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/aBbmfz6ZFc14Fg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, вы переключили перспективу из перспективы по умолчанию Java (или Java EE в зависимости от версии eclipse). Часто это происходит, когда начинаете использовать отладчик, eclipse предлагает переключаться на перспективу Debug.

Пункты меню доступны в зависимости от перспективы и в перспективе Debug по умолчанию доступны только Project, Example и Other.

Текущая перспектива обычно показана на тулбаре:
[image: текущая перспектива]

Чтоб изменить доступные пункты для перспективы зайдите в `Window -> Perspective -> Customize Perspective...` и там выбирайте:

[image: выбор пунктов меню]

Comment: Спасибо, прямо в точку, +10000 к карме вам в копилку)